# When does mutate use row elements of a variable vs. the entire column vector?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I've been trying to understand when it's necessary to use apply or map functions and using formulas within them, without much success because I can't see the logic behind what is being called or not. Here's a simple example using mutate:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  a = 1:5,
  b = 3:7,
  c = 5:9
)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = a)
```

Each element of new is the corresponding element of a.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = 1 == a)
```

Each element of new is TRUE of FALSE depending on the corresponding element of a.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = 3 %in% a)
```

Each element of new is the same as it checks whether 3 is in the entire vector a, not just the corresponding element.

So when does it use the element from the variable with the matching row, and when does it use the entire variable vector? I don't see a logical pattern that helps me determine whether I need to be using apply or map.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = str_c(a, b, sep = "..."))
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with functions, but here it uses the corresponding elements of a and b rather than the entire vectors.

On a similar note, if I have a list vector in my tibble:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  prb = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3),
  dist = list(rnorm(5, sd = 1), 
           rnorm(5, sd = 5),
           rnorm(5, sd = 10))
)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(new = prb * dist)
```

This gives an error, even though 0.2 * rnorm(5, sd = 1) does not.

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(one = map2(prb, dist, ~.x * .y))
```

So I have to use something like this. Why?

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(new = dist)
```

This duplicates the dist column, so it must be looking at each element of dist?

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(new = dist[1])
```

But this doesn't work like I'd want, because it returns the first element of the entire dist list (which is a vector of 5 values). I want the first element of the vector that corresponds with each row, so it returns a single number. Yes I know I can do that with the map function and a formula, but what is the logic behind why it works or doesn't?

Comment: It does the exact same thing in each of your first three examples: every element of `a` is examined to generate the resulting new column.

Comment: ...or maybe what you're confused about is not the behavior of `mutate()` but the semantic meaning of the actual code producing the new column. For example, `1 == a` is a different question, semantically, than `3 %in% a`. As long as the result produces a vector of the correct length, mutate() won't complain.

Comment: Right, and `3 %in% a` return a vector of length 1, which is then recycled. Maybe that's the part you're missing. `mutate()` will allow results of either length equal to the number of rows, or just 1 element, in which case it recycles. That's all it cares about.

Comment: ...but your use of the phrase "uses the entire vector" is really sort of misleading here, because in both cases the entire vector `a` is "used". Each element is checked when using `==` and (in principle) every element of `a` will need to be examined to determine the result of `3 %in% a`. So the whole vector is being "used" in either case.

Comment: Sorry, having trouble formatting comments. Does it try to use the entire vector first and only use corresponding elements if that doesn't work? Edit:...Your last comment clarified everything for me, thanks.